# system.net.mail is too slow

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, system.net.mail

am using system.net.mail to send email as shown below, but its too slow. it takes about a minute to send, whats wrong with my code. Am calling the code below in backgroundworker_dowork.

[edit]: is there a faster alternative, maybe free or open source code

```
' send the email '
Dim smtp As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient()
Dim mail As New MailMessage()
Dim i As Long = 0

' SMTP settings  '
With smtp
    .Host = Trim$(sSMTP)
    .Port = Trim$(iPort)
    .UseDefaultCredentials = False
    .Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(sUserID, sPword)
    .EnableSsl = bSSL
End With

' create the mail '
With mail
    If sAttachment <> vbNullString Then
        .Attachments.Add(New Net.Mail.Attachment(sAttachment))
    End If
    .From = New MailAddress(sFromEmail, sFromName)
    .ReplyTo = New MailAddress(sReplyTo)
    .Subject = sSubject
    .IsBodyHtml = True
    .Body = sMessage
End With

For i = 0 To lstRecipients.Count - 1
    mail.To.Add(lstRecipients(i))
    Debug.Print(lstRecipients(i))
    Try
        smtp.Send(mail)
        lSent += 1
        bwrkMain.ReportProgress(CInt(100 * (i + 1) / iTotalRecipients))
        SetStatus("Sent:" & lstRecipients(i))
    Catch ex As Exception
        bwrkMain.ReportProgress(CInt(100 * (i + 1) / iTotalRecipients))
        SetStatus("Not Sent:" & lstRecipients(i))
    End Try
    mail.To.Clear()
Next
```

Comment: Email doesn't necessarily send instantaneously. It takes time to send and receive data over the Internet. Why do you assume that taking 1 minute to send means that it isn't working properly?

Comment: How many recipients are there? Are you sending files as attachments? Your code seems OK, maybe there is a problem with the mail server.

Comment: @Jorge Villuendas i am looping throug recipients list, but for testing, i just use two recipients. There is no attchment in the test, but i hope to test this too. And am using google smtp server for test

Comment: @Cody Gray when you send mail through the web, it is almost instant, or t least takes less that 10 seconds to receive it on the receiving end

Comment: @Smith it seems that google delays email sended through their smtp server to prevent spam http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629477/using-gmail-as-smtp-server-in-java-web-app-is-slow/4508888#4508888

Comment: Now it dosen't even send, it says `the operation have timed out after about 30s of a mminutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave it up to the SMTP server to distribute the email to the recipients.

```
For i = 0 To lstRecipients.Count - 1
    mail.To.Add(lstRecipients(i))
Next
smtp.Send(mail)
```

Use the Bcc property if you don't want the recipient to see the other names.

Comment: He calls mail.To.Clear() at the end of the loop

Comment: All that does is get rid of the people that the emails are being sent to Hans method, using BCC, does the same thing.

Comment: Indeed, wow, that really should be moved before the Add call for the sake of readability.  Invoking answer #2.

Comment: i need confirmation to know which mail was sent and which one is not sent, so i can't use bbc

Answer (score 1):

You might want to switch to "pickup mode" where the mail client drops the message(s) in the local IIS SMTP dispatch location instead. That way you're sending mail asynchronously (sorta), although you'll have to [install and configure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772058%28WS.10%29.aspx) the SMTP component.

Your code seems fine to me, the lag must be in the relay server you're using.