# system.net.mail does not send mail

Tags: vb.net, smtpclient

i am developing with vb2005, using system.net.mail to send mail using google configuration. a full sample of my code was [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284514/system-net-mail-is-too-slow) earlier

```
        With smtp
            .Host = "smtp.google.com"
            .Port = 465
            .UseDefaultCredentials = False
            .Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(mygoogleemail, mypass)
            .EnableSsl = true
            .Timeout = 60000
        End With
```

i get the operation has timed out. if i change the port to 587, it says that `the server does not support secure connection`

[EDIT]
could firewall be blocking it?

is there anyway to specify sending application name?

Comment: Google will not let you use its SMTP server to send spam.  Increase the timeout to at least 5 minutes.  Try the gmail.com host.

Comment: @Hans Passant am just testing my app with 1 email only, and it dose not send

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Dim myLogin As New NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password")
Dim msg As New MailMessage("username@gmail.com", "to@somedomain.com", "subjectLine", "emailBodyText")

msg.IsBodyHtml = True

Try
    Dim client As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    client.EnableSsl = True
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false
    client.Credentials = myLogin
    client.Send(msg)
Catch ex As SmtpException
    msgbox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

If you get the timeout then troubleshoot

1. Go to gmail.com and make sure you can loging with those credentials.
2. Login to gmail account and go to settings and make sure POP/IMAP is setup. I don't think they allow you to send mail thru your account unless this is turned on.
3. Try changing the port to 25 with SSL.
4. Try to TELNET the mail server to see if you are able to send relay mails via your ISP

   Open command prompt and type (without quotes) telnet smtp.gmail.com 25

If you get a timeout then the problem is either your local LAN is blocking mails or your ISP.

Comment: I can telnet to google at 587, but when i use my app, it says the operation has timedout

Comment: Then the problem must be in the GMail account setup. Try using an email client like Outlook and setup an account with the same credentials and see if you are able to send emails.

Comment: actually, i just used another smtp server, and it worked. i don't know what is wrong with google

Comment: Ha! Then your gmail account is not properly configured for access by another client (e.g. POP3) OR your "FROM" address does not match the username so the connection is dropped.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the answer at : [Sending email through Gmail SMTP server with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c)

Just to see if that works.

Note that in the answer to his solution he mentions web.config changes lower in the post not accepted as the answer

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="myusername@gmail.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
      <network defaultCredentials="false" enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" password="password" userName="myusername@gmail.com"/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>  
</system.net>
```

Comment: is there any difference in what i have done here and what is done in the link you posted?

Comment: Yes, he mentioned web.config changes that had to be made.

Comment: am not developing a web app, instead a desktop app

Comment: If thats the case there should be appsettings.config or program.exe.config

Answer (score 1):

The port was right in the OP, but the host was wrong

```
    With smtp
        .Port = 465 '465 for ssl
        .EnableSsl = True
        .UseDefaultCredentials = False
        .Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("myusername@gmail.com", "yourpassword")
        .Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    End With
```

And just to verify, you have pop enabled in gmail, correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **TWO STEP VERIFICATION** for gmail, then disable it first and then try again with this code

```
Dim myLogin As New NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password")
Dim msg As New MailMessage("username@gmail.com", "to@somedomain.com", "subjectLine", "emailBodyText")

msg.IsBodyHtml = True

Try
    Dim client As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    client.EnableSsl = True
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false
    client.Credentials = myLogin
    client.Send(msg)
Catch ex As SmtpException
    msgbox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Answer (score -1):

The Port number is 587.

And also, try this order as per [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c/3797154#3797154)

```
    With smtp
        .UseDefaultCredentials = False
        .Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("myusername@gmail.com", "mypwd")
        .Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        .Port = 587
        .EnableSsl = true
    End With
```

Comment: i still get the same error `the server does not support secure connection`

Comment: @smith: can you post the exact code you are using. i dont see smtp.google.com enclosed in double quotes